# Why is my install code for Anaconda Launcher and Jupyter Notebook not working in IDLE for Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, python-idle

I am trying to install Anaconda Launcher and was supplied the following code to type into the terminal:

> > > conda install -c anaconda launcher

I also tried and failed to install just Jupyter Notebook with the following code:

> > > python -m pip install jupyter notebook

Both lines of code yielded: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Those are shell commands, and you are trying to type them into a Python repl, presumably.

Comment: The messages are from python, not IDLE, and you would see the same if you entered them into the default interactive interpreter instead of IDLE's gui version.  Interactive python is not a terminal.

Comment: I downloaded Python 2.7.13 on my Mac and it only installed IDLE and Python Launcher. IDLE automatically opens a screen called '*Python 2.7.13 Shell*'. Is there a different form of this code I should type into the shell?